# How to prevent spam when sender email is never the same?

Tags: email, spam

Recently, I have been massively spammed by emails, and unsubscribing via the link doesn't work. Another option is to block the sender, but the problem is that the sender email is never the same. It's always in the form of Support@********.de, but the ******** part is never the same.

They all go to the junk folder, but some legit emails also go to the junk folder, so I can't just ignore this folder. And as I receive hundreds of emails, it prevents me from reading the real mails.

Is this problem common, and what can I do about it?

For what it's worth, my email is Hotmail, and I use Outlook Live to read them.

Comment: Look in the headers of the spam messages.  Do these messages pass hotmail's SPF and/or DKIM checks?

Comment: I'm going back and forth on this question. You are basically asking for generic advice on how to improve your spam filters. As such, the question is either too broad, or the answer is to use better automatic filters (use another service's filters that meet your needs).

Answer (score 2):

Spam is a security concern because it can contain various phishing and malware attacks. This should be really concerning because the more spam you get the greater chance you will click a link thinking it's legitimate and get hacked.

Once you get on the spam lists, there is nothing you can do to get off of them. It now becomes a question of how important that account is to you?

Hotmail/Outlook is notoriously bad a spam filtering. Contrast that with Gmail or iCloud which have such good spam filtering that I NEVER see spam. "Google says less than 0.1 percent of email in the average Gmail inbox is spam while wanted mail in spam folders is under 0.05 percent." [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/say-goodbye-hotmail-spam/)

So, my recommendation would be to open a Gmail or iCloud account and start to gradually migrate your contacts/mailing lists over to that account.

But if you insist on staying with your current account, there are a few things you can do to mitigate some of that spam:

1. Instead of deleting spam, mark it as 'junk'. There should be a button for that. That will better tweak the algorithms.
2. There is an Outlook mail setting 'Block attachments, pictures, and links from anyone not in my Safe senders and domains list' checkbox. Then add the senders and domains you trust to this list.
3. Don't reply to spam or unsubscribe from spam messages. Don't even look at it as the sender can have a tracker that shows you opened it.
4. Never tried a spam plugin myself, but these may be worth a shot: [Top Anti-Spam Add-Ins for Outlook](https://www.lifewire.com/top-anti-spam-plugins-outlook-1173636)

Alternatively, you can forward your mail to Gmail and take advantage of its spam filters. You even have the option of sending and receiving Hotmail from a Gmail account. See [here](https://www.techjunkie.com/forward-hotmail-to-gmail/)

Comment: Note: Part of the way Google does this is by treating all non-Google email as extra suspicious, and making it harder for small people to run their own mail servers without being treated as spam - so if you switch to Gmail for this reason, you're contributing to the centralization of email.

Answer (score -2):

In spam detection there are some headers that can be faked easily and others don't, my recommendation is to check if the email contains DMARC, DKIM headers in order to verify the reputation of the email, by doing this you can trust other headers more than others and dont take into consideration certain headers that are subject to be modified by spammers.

Comment: This is not possible at scale. The OP says that they are already going to junk, so they are already marked as suspect.

Answer (score -2):

What you can do it to use the rule option to filter those spam emails and move them into a specific folder (could be a new folder with the name ToBeDeleted for example). Then, mark this new folder for automatic deletion (all email messages in this folder will be automatically deleted)

The catch is you want your filtering rules to not be very specific so it mismatches spams and also not very general so it matches important messages. It is best to start with very specific rules to avoid matching important emails

Here are some links that should help you

[Manage email messages by using rules](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59#ID0EAAFAAA=Step_1)

[How to Auto Delete email in Outlook selectively](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/auto-delete-mail-outlook)

Comment: The OP says that they are already being handled by junk rules. The question is how to target spam more accurately. You have basically said "just make a rule". The question is how to craft those rules.

Comment: @schroeder I am sure you understand he needs to write the rules himself. No one can write the rules for him.  Those are custom rules, I do not think he already knows how to create rules. So a bit of regular expression and probably he will end up deleting some important messages until he adjusts the rules :)

Comment: Right, but your answer doesn't help with any of that, if that's even possible.